# Error "Invalid JSON Keys cannot be empty or contain $#[]./" upon uploading JSON file in Firebase realtime database

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a huge database consisting of multiple tables and each table consists of thousands of records. I had exported the database from my `xampp` local server in JSON format:

```js
[
{"type":"header","version":"5.1.1","comment":"Export to JSON plugin for PHPMyAdmin"},
{"type":"database","name":"izqlinmg_electric"},
{"type":"table","name":"book_master","database":"izqlinmg_electric","data":
[
{"books":"00001"},
{"books":"00002"},
{"books":"00003"},
{"books":"00004"},
{"books":"00005"},
{"books":"00006"},
{"books":"00007"},
{"books":"00008"},
{"books":"00009"},
{"books":"00010"},
{"books":"00011"},
{"books":"00012"},
{"books":"00013"},
{"books":"00014"},
{"books":"00016"},
{"books":"00018"},
{"books":"00019"},
{"books":"00021"},
{"books":"00023"},
{"books":"00024"},
{"books":"00025"},
{"books":"00026"},
{"books":"00027"},
{"books":"00028"},
{"books":"00029"},
{"books":"00032"},
{"books":"00033"},
{"books":"00034"},
{"books":"00035"},
{"books":"00036"},
{"books":"00037"},
{"books":"00038"},
{"books":"00042"},
{"books":"00043"},
{"books":"00044"},
{"books":"00045"},
{"books":"00046"},
{"books":"00047"},
{"books":"00048"},
{"books":"00049"},
{"books":"00050"},
{"books":"00051"},
{"books":"00052"},
{"books":"00053"},
{"books":"00054"},
{"books":"00055"},
{"books":"00056"},
{"books":"00057"},
{"books":"00058"},
{"books":"00059"},
{"books":"00060"},
{"books":"00061"},
{"books":"00062"},
{"books":"00063"},
{"books":"00064"},
{"books":"00065"},
{"books":"00066"},
{"books":"00068"},
{"books":"00069"},
{"books":"00070"},
{"books":"00071"},
{"books":"00072"},
{"books":"00073"},
{"books":"10001"},
{"books":"10002"},
{"books":"10003"},
{"books":"10004"},
{"books":"10005"},
{"books":"10006"},
{"books":"10007"},
{"books":"20001"},
{"books":"20002"},
{"books":"20003"},
{"books":"20004"},
{"books":"20005"},
{"books":"20006"},
{"books":"20007"},
{"books":"20008"},
{"books":"20009"},
{"books":"20010"},
{"books":"20011"},
{"books":"20012"}
]
}
,{"type":"table","name":"colony_master","database":"izqlinmg_electric","data":
[...
```

Now I want to import this database to Firebase realtime db. But upon uploading I keep getting this error:

> Invalid JSON Keys cannot be empty or contain $#[]./

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory: keys (the things to the left of `:`) in the Firebase Realtime Database cannot contain certain characters, and one or more of your keys contains one of those characters.

You'll have to remove the offending characters and try the import again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is the array. You need to convert it to an object with `{}` instead of `[]`. Other issues I had to solve that were not obvious from the error:

- you must remove trailing commas from the last line in each object (prettier even adds these by default, but Firebase can't handle them)
- the keys must be wrapped in quotes